# Storing a hexadecimal value in a variable (Dim xx as "Hex") in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, hex

How can I store a hexadecimal number in a variable without it becoming a decimal?

Or do I **have** to store it as either a string or integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers in .NET are not stored as decimal, they are stored as binary in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation. Both decimal and hexadecimal are just different ways of reoresenting the number in a more human-friendly way.

If you want to output a number as hexadecimal you can use the "x" or "X" format specifier with the ToString method (which output lower- and upper-case respectively) with an optional fixed number of characters specified as "n" where n is the number of characters.

Some examples of outputting an integer as hex:

```
Dim n as Integer = &HBEEF;
Console.WriteLine(n.ToString("x")) ' output in lower case, e.g. beef '
Console.WriteLine(n.ToString("X")) ' output in upper case, e.g. BEEF '
Console.WriteLine(n.ToString("X8")) ' upper case & 8 chars, e.g. 0000BEEF '
```

Comment: Did you answer this question before lunch?  :)

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString) doesn't mention the colon and it doesn't work with it for me in VB2008. Should be "X8".

Comment: @Martin - Fixed. Not sure what I was thinking... Amazed it has taken over a year for anyone to notice.

Answer (score 4):

I think you've misunderstood how numbers work.

Numbers themselves aren't hex, decimal or binary - that's just their representation, whether in code or in memory.<sup>1</sup>

What you get when you add together five and five is ten, whether you format that as 10 or &H0A.

So these statements are *exactly* equivalent:

```
 Dim x As Integer = 16
 Dim x As Integer = &H10
```

Both put the same value into the variable.

If you want to later *format* that value as hex, then you should do so - e.g. with the "x" format specifier. But the value itself isn't hex or decimal.

```
Dim y As Integer = &H23
Console.WriteLine(y) ' Prints 35
Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("x")) ' Prints 23
```

EDIT: If you *really* want to do this, you could always create your own structure which took an integer value in its constructor and overrode `ToString` to format it in hex. I'd strongly recommend that you don't do this though.

---

<sup>1</sup> Admittedly the representation can significantly affect what you can *do* with the number and what results you'll get - as seen by the difference between `Double` and `Decimal`. We'll leave that out of the equation for the moment though.

Comment: what I mean is how can I store it without having to continuously do `Hex(xx)` to "convert" to hex when i retrieve it.

Comment: @Jonathan - You can't; there is no hexadecimal based number in .NET.

Comment: Where do you need it as hex? In the debugger? I suspect there's a debugger option somewhere. For formatting to a string, you should use the standard formatting routines.

Answer (score 3):

If you store a value in a variable, it will be neither in decimal nor hexadecimal form. Eventually it ends up in your computer's RAM in binary form. To the computer, the decimal number `17` and hexadecimal `&H11` are identical. The difference is purely lexical and disappears once the compiler has done its work.

If you want to preserve a value's representation in hexadecimal form, you need to store it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim myNum as Integer = &H100 '&HB

Console.WriteLine(myNum)
```

EDIT: You could store the expression as string & use `Int.Parse` or any other `Parse` or `TryParse` method, if that helps.